# $f:(1,-\infty) \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}:f(x,y)=(\ln(x)^{y})$ is Borel measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the function $f:(1,\infty) \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}:f(x,y)=(\ln(x)^{y})$ is a Borel measurable function .

First I thought that the function is continuous so it needed to be Borel measurable, but I think that's to easy.

As followed I tried to prove that $f^{-1}(A)$ is a Borelsubset for every Borelsubset $A \subset [0,\infty]$. My intentions were to prove it for $A \in B$ with $B$ the smalest $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,\infty]$

I don't get anything usefull on paper to prove it correctly.

EDIT: my first thought was correct. Because the function is continuous it is enough so you can see it's a Borrel measurable function.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, hence Borel measurable.

Comment: so that's enough?

Comment: Do you mean $\infty$ instead of $-\infty$?

Comment: yes sorry i will change it

Comment: That is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

my first thought was correct. Because the function is continuous it is enough so you can see it's a Borrel measurable function